# Undesired output when transforming values to integrers using as.integrer in R

Tags: r

I have the dataset below:

```
> head(GLM_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   hour [6]
   hour Feeding Foraging Standing ID    Area     Feeding_Foraging
  <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>               <dbl>
1     0    3.61     23.2     1    41361 Seronera             26.8
2     1    2.85     24.2     1    41361 Seronera             27.0
3     2    2.5      24.3     2    41361 Seronera             26.8
4     3    6.92     18.6     3.89 41361 Seronera             25.6
5     4    7.5      17.6     3.78 41361 Seronera             25.1
6     5    7.26     19.6     2.45 41361 Seronera             26.8
```

And would like to round off numbers in columns `Standing` and `Feeding_Foraging`. I'm using `as.integrer()` as follows:

```
> GLM_df$Standing<-as.integer(GLM_df$Standing)
> GLM_df$Feeding_Foraging<-as.integer(GLM_df$Feeding_Foraging)
> head(GLM_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   hour [6]
   hour Feeding Foraging Standing ID    Area     Feeding_Foraging
  <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <int> <chr> <chr>               <int>
1     0    3.61     23.2        1 41361 Seronera               26
2     1    2.85     24.2        1 41361 Seronera               27
3     2    2.5      24.3        2 41361 Seronera               26
4     3    6.92     18.6        3 41361 Seronera               25
5     4    7.5      17.6        3 41361 Seronera               25
6     5    7.26     19.6        2 41361 Seronera               26
```

However, this is rounding `26.8` into `26` and I would like `26.8` to be rounded up to `27`. On the other hand, I would like values having less than a `0.5` decimal component (ex: `25.1`) to be rounded down as using `as.integrer()` (ex: `25`).

Is there a function I can use for that or do I need code?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: use the `round` function which has your desired properties

Comment: why not use `round(your_vector,0)` ?

Comment: Thank you I used `round()` and solved the issue